# Powershell : Highlight excel cell Interior using condition

Tags: excel, powershell

I want to highlight an excel cell interior using powershell , am able to change color of font , but not entire cell color

[image: Excel Sheet]

So this is how my excel sheet is , it checks whether the cell has "Matching" and changes color according to that

```
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$excel.Visible = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\test4.xls")
$sheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet

$xlCellTypeLastCell = 11

$used = $sheet.usedRange 
$lastCell = $used.SpecialCells($xlCellTypeLastCell) 
$row = $lastCell.row # goes to the last used row in the worksheet
$column = $lastCell.Column; 
$i = 0 
for ($J = 2; $J -le $column; $j++) {
     $sheet.Cells.Item($i,$j).Interior.ColorIndex = 48
     $sheet.Cells.Item($i,$j).Font.Bold=$True
}
for ($i = 2; $i -le $row; $i++) {
    for($j = 5 ; $j -le $column ; $j++){
        if (($sheet.cells.Item($i,$j).Value()) -like "*Matching") {
            $sheet.Cells.Item($i,$j).Font.ColorIndex = 10
            $sheet.Cells.Item($i,$j).Font.Bold = $true
        }
        if(($sheet.cells.Item($i,$j).Value()) -like "*Not Matching"){
            $sheet.Cells.Item($i,$j).Font.ColorIndex = 3
            $sheet.Cells.Item($i,$j).Font.Bold = $true
        }
    }
}

$workbook.SaveAs("C:\Users\output.xls")
$workbook.Close()
```

this is code , Only problem is when i give

```
$sheet.Cells.Item($i,$j).Interior.ColorIndex = 48
```

It's giving me an exception

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
```

I want my table to look like this ,
[image: Output Excel Template]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from my comments.

[PowerShell Excel and Conditional Formatting](https://dfinke.github.io/powershell/2020/05/02/PowerShell-Excel-and-Conditional-Formatting.html)

```
# Quick Find the Top 10 Months
$xl = Open-ExcelPackage -Path $xlfile
Add-ConditionalFormatting -Worksheet $xl.StoresTop10Sales -Address $xl.StoresTop10Sales.dimension.address -RuleType Top -ForegroundColor white -BackgroundColor green -ConditionValue 10
Close-ExcelPackage $xl -Show

# Databars
Add-ConditionalFormatting -Worksheet $xl.StoresSalesDataBar -Address $xl.StoresSalesDataBar.dimension.address -DataBarColor Red

# Color Scales
Add-ConditionalFormatting -Worksheet $xl.StoresSalesTwoColorScale -Address $xl.StoresSalesDataBar.dimension.address -RuleType TwoColorScale
```

Use this module: [ImportExcel 5.4.4](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.4.4/Content/AddConditionalFormatting.ps1)

```
AddConditionalFormatting.ps1
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you are saying "I want to do with Powershell what Excel can do automatically using condional formatting", do you mean by that:

- You are not aware of conditional formatting, or:
- Conditional formatting means modifying something in your Excel file, which you can't do, hence the Powershell.  Like this your question becomes "How to configure conditional formatting via Powershell?".

Which one is it?

Comment: i want to do conditional formating in excel using powershell

Comment: Yet, what did you search for? There are plenty of articles that cover this.    ['powershell excel conditional formatting'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell+excel+conditional+formatting%27&form=ANNTH1&refig=3ea7871378914b47b3fc270244d3113f&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell+excel+conditional+formatting%27&sc=1-41&qs=n&sk=&cvid=3ea7871378914b47b3fc270244d3113f)